# Firefox text search - How to disable automatic wrap-around when reaching the end of a document

Tags: firefox, search

While performing a text search on text-heavy pages, after reaching the last result and pressing F3, Firefox automatically continues from the top with only a minor indication next to the search text bar (very bottom) that it has "*reached the end of page, continued from top*". I would like to prevent this "wrap-around" search functionality, or if possible, ask me if I want to search from the top again (which is par for the course with respect to most other programs which provide search functionality).

I have googled (most results relate to search engines or the search bar at the top) as well as tried digging around **about:config** hoping to find something, alas, I am still clueless if this is even possible.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is impossible.

The bug-report
[Bring back option for wrap/no wrap when using find toolbar](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=279014)
was opened 16 years ago.
Its status is "RESOLVED WONTFIX" since 16 years ago.
Users kept hammering on this decision for 8 more years, without any result.

The person that closed the bug-report,
[Mike Connor](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mconnorto/?originalSubdomain=ca),
Mozilla Director and past Firefox Architect, did write this:

> There's no point in adding a preference for the sake of "user choice."
> In fact, there is a much greater benefit in reducing the degree of
> user choice and configuration required, and focusing on creating an
> optimal experience without configuration.
>
> Unless you can come up with a use-case where this is actually
> useful/needed, that's the way it will remain.

Later on he added:

> No, the method of enabling it isn't the issue.  Its the UI itself once
> enabled that I'm talking about.
>
> **Wrap by default and without interruption is the choice we've made.
> We're not going to change core behaviour like this.** We don't want
> dialogs of any sort, so those suggestions are out the window.
>
> If someone really wants to implement a different find mechanism, then
> that's what extensions are for.

And more:

> We chose a different method, one that has found a great deal of user
> acceptance.  Like any decision we've made from the outset, there will
> always be someone who wants a different way of doing things.  Instead
> of maintaining multiple codepaths and multiple prefs, we've elected to
> leave alternate ideas like this to extensions.  **You might not agree
> with how we do things, but that's been the driving force behind the
> project.**

I have not found any add-on for disabling search wrap.

My answer is then negative - this is impossible to do.
I don't know if it's possible to do so by add-on, but nobody has written
one till now.

Comment: Looks like my question is a duplicate! The last comment on that bug report points here: https://superuser.com/questions/472039/no-wrap-when-using-find-toolbar

Sadly, the accepted answer add-on description says that the functionality to trigger on Find Wrapped events (noise-TypeAheadFind.FIND_WRAPPED) is only available with legacy Firefox < 57 versions. I was however able to get the 2nd answer from Lekensteyn to work. It's not optimal, but it's definitely better than nothing!

Comment: I saw this post while writing my answer, but didn't mention it because I didn't think it answered your question, since the indication is only displayed once and stops nothing. In any case, dating from 2012, that old post can hardly count as duplicate nowadays.